# Android device group not receiving messages

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I didn't change anything in my app since several months but starting from 11th June I'm not able to receive any message sent by Firebase cloud messaging. It has been reported by several customers and I can confirm that it doesn't work anymore. No firmware change or anything at least on my phone. I used *exactly* the same code you find [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/device-group#managing-device-groups-on-android-client-apps). The message is sent, the callback `onMessageSent` in the `FirebaseMessagingService` is called correctly, but I'm not able to receive anything using the same account on another phone. Is there any big change I miss it? ***My configuration doesn't use a server*** so I can't check any log server side. Any tips?

Comment: Please understand I mean no disrespect but these are the questions I would ask first:
 - Has the linked firebase page code changed at all, double check each line carefully, maybe the access expects a new parameter?
 - Does your firebase account still work? Is there perhaps a close/block on your account? If you have been away for several months, make sure to clear the cobwebs on the DB.
 - Check through release logs for both firebase and android SDK and see if there has been anything that could have an effect.

I'm sure you've checked these already but sometimes the obvious is the answer.

Comment: Already checked, firebase account still works, my app still uses the correct methods, there's no log I can check because logcat provides no error and since I'm using a no server configuration, there's nothing I can check as I said.

Comment: if you log the result of the call, does anything come out at all? Do you not even get a http code back in the response object?

Comment: I use Android firebase library, not just http. There's no error logged in logcat and onMessageSent callback is called correctly but message is not received

Comment: Few questions for ya: `1`, did you confirm that they are not being received in both the foreground and the background? `2`, Have you tried deleting and recreating the Firebase Instance ID? It's possible it has just expired. `3` Is this happening on both ios and Android? Or only Android?

Comment: 1) yes 2) I don't know how to do it, remember I'm using a no server configuration 3) My app is Android only

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The official reply I've gotten from Firebase is: **they simply don't support the no-server configuration anymore**.

So after 30 emails with Firebase support here's the surprise: there's nothing wrong with my code/project, and the funny thing is that they don't know why and how it worked before! Unfortunately, they didn't advise anyone about this big change, so any app based on Android device groups without a server doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Crazy they would change it without any notification.

Comment: Please see my answer, this functionality still works with the legacy API

Comment: The no server configuration doesn't work anymore, it's an official reply by firebase team

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible answer to your question -

Firstly, you say that '*But I'm not able to receive anything using the same account on another phone*'. Device Messaging via FCM uses the device registration token as the point of contact and not the account. Therefore, you might not receive messages from FCM with the same account on a different device.

Secondly, you can only have 20 devices registered to each token group. The Firebase Docs also mention that you usually need an app server to do device to device messaging.

Remember that this kind of device to device messaging is used only for notifications, not for sending chat messages or anything of that kind. If you want to implement notifications without an app server, try this -

```java
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;
import androidx.legacy.content.WakefulBroadcastReceiver;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

public class NotificationIntentService extends IntentService {

    private static int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    private static final String ACTION_START = "ACTION_START";
    private static final String ACTION_DELETE = "ACTION_DELETE";

    public NotificationIntentService() {
        super(NotificationIntentService.class.getSimpleName());
    }

    public static Intent createIntentStartNotificationService(Context context) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotificationIntentService.class);
        intent.setAction(ACTION_START);
        return intent;
    }

    public static Intent createIntentDeleteNotification(Context context) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotificationIntentService.class);
        intent.setAction(ACTION_DELETE);
        return intent;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.w(String.valueOf(new NotificationIntentService()), "onHandleIntent, started handling a notification event");
        try {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (ACTION_START.equals(action)) {
                processStartNotification();
            }
            if (ACTION_DELETE.equals(action)) {
                processDeleteNotification(intent);
            }
        } finally {
            WakefulBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
        }
    }

    private void processDeleteNotification(Intent intent) {
        // Log something?
    }

    private void processStartNotification() {

        // Do something. For example, fetch fresh data from backend to create a rich notification?

        NOTIFICATION_ID += 1;

        Intent intent = new Intent(NotificationIntentService.this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(NotificationIntentService.this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

         String channelId = getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id);
         Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
         NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
                                        new NotificationCompat.Builder(NotificationIntentService.this, channelId)
                                                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.chat)
                                                .setContentTitle("Title")
                                                .setContentText("Text")
                                                .setAutoCancel(true)
                                                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                                                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

                                notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
                                notificationBuilder.setDeleteIntent(NotificationEventReceiver.getDeleteIntent(NotificationIntentService.this));

                                NotificationManager notificationManager =
                                        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

                                // Since android Oreo notification channel is needed.
                                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                                    NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId,
                                            "channel_id",
                                            NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
                                    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
                                }

                                notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.build());

    }
}
```

```java
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.legacy.content.WakefulBroadcastReceiver;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class NotificationEventReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String ACTION_START_NOTIFICATION_SERVICE = "ACTION_START_NOTIFICATION_SERVICE";
    private static final String ACTION_DELETE_NOTIFICATION = "ACTION_DELETE_NOTIFICATION";
    private static final int NOTIFICATIONS_INTERVAL_IN_FIFTEEN_MINUTES = 0;

    public static void setupAlarm(Context context) {
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        PendingIntent alarmIntent = getStartPendingIntent(context);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                getTriggerAt(new Date()),
                600000,
                alarmIntent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        Intent serviceIntent = null;
        if (ACTION_START_NOTIFICATION_SERVICE.equals(action)) {
            Log.w(getClass().getSimpleName(), "onReceive from alarm, starting notification service");
            serviceIntent = NotificationIntentService.createIntentStartNotificationService(context);
        } else if (ACTION_DELETE_NOTIFICATION.equals(action)) {
            Log.w(getClass().getSimpleName(), "onReceive delete notification action, starting notification service to handle delete");
            serviceIntent = NotificationIntentService.createIntentDeleteNotification(context);
        }

        if (serviceIntent != null) {
            startWakefulService(context, serviceIntent);
        }
    }

    private static long getTriggerAt(Date now) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(now);
        //calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR, NOTIFICATIONS_INTERVAL_IN_HOURS);
        return calendar.getTimeInMillis();
    }

    private static PendingIntent getStartPendingIntent(Context context) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotificationEventReceiver.class);
        intent.setAction(ACTION_START_NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    }

    public static PendingIntent getDeleteIntent(Context context) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotificationEventReceiver.class);
        intent.setAction(ACTION_DELETE_NOTIFICATION);
        return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    }
}
```

```java
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public final class NotificationServiceStarterReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        NotificationEventReceiver.setupAlarm(context);
    }
}
```

I'm sorry, but I won't be able to tell you much more without seeing the code.

Hope this helps.

Sources -

- Firebase Docs - https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#senderid
- Firebase Docs - https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/device-group#managing-device-groups-on-android-client-apps

Comment: sorry but your reply doesn't make sense, I used the same code for three years for device to device communication without server and starting from 11th June it doesn't work anymore. The code is exactly what you find in firebase docs as I posted.

Answer (score 0):

Migrate from GoogleAuthUtil and Plus.API

If you integrated with Google Sign-In in the past using GoogleAuthUtil.getToken or Plus.API, you should migrate to the newest Sign-In API for greater security and a better user experience.

Android client side
Remove the GET_ACCOUNTS (Contacts) permission if you request it
Switch any code using `GoogleAuthUtil`, `Plus.API`, `AccountPicker.newChooseAccountIntent()`, or `AccountManager.newChooseAccountIntent()` to `Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API` with `GoogleSignInOptions.Builder.requestIdToken(...)` configuration.

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/migration-guide

Please note that the [Migrate from legacy HTTP to HTTP v1](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/migrate-v1) Cautions: Any apps that use device group messaging may prefer to not upgrade. HTTP v1 does not support this feature of the FCM legacy API.

Comment: GoogleAuthUtil Is needed if you at the link in the question

Comment: I think the documentation is old, it is using a deprecated method.